# Print multiple lines with variables in a single print() statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to do something like this (using python 3):

```
le = "\n"
var1 = 2
var2 = 5

print("INFORMATION"+le
      "-----------"+le
      "Variable1: {}".format(var1)+le
      "Variable2: {}".format(var2)+le
      )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. take a look at [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print).

General example:

```
var1 = 2
var2 = 5
print("INFORMATION", 
      "------------",
      "Variable1: {}".format(var1),
      "Variable2: {}".format(var2), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print("INFORMATION\n"
      "-----------\n"
      "Variable1: {}\n".format(var1),
      "Variable2: {}".format(var2)
      )
In [24]: print("INFORMATION"'\n'
   ....:           "-----------"'\n'
   ....:           "Variable1: {}\n".format(var1),
   ....:           "Variable2: {}".format(var2)
   ....:           )
INFORMATION
-----------
Variable1: 2
Variable2: 5


print("INFORMATION",
      "-----------",
      "Variable1: {}".format(var1),
      "Variable2: {}".format(var2),
      sep='\n')
In [30]: print("INFORMATION",
   ....:       "-----------",
   ....:       "Variable1: {}".format(var1),
   ....:       "Variable2: {}".format(var2),
   ....:       sep='\n')
INFORMATION
-----------
Variable1: 2
Variable2: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store this string in an object and then print it:

```
out = "INFORMATION"+le+"-----------"+le+"Variable1: {}".format(var1)+le+"Variable2: {}".format(var2)+le
print(out)
```

Or if you want to do it easier you can also do like that:

```
print("INFORMATION\n-----------\nVariable1: {}\nVariable2: {}\n".format(var1, var2))
```

Or if it is too long and you want to spare it in different lines in your code:

```
out = "Information\n" /
      "-----------\n"
```